# cellForItemAtIndexPath get the wrong value of indexPath in block

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I create a button in a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, and add a target in the button block like:

```
@interface MYCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^clickButtonBlock)(BOOL boolValue);
@end
```

and I set the block to delete the cell I click the button in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, like:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [strongSelf.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [strongSelf.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]]];
    [strongSelf.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0]]];
}];
```

after I delete the first cell. The next cell's `NSIndexPath` was wrong, And the function `[collectionView indexPathForCell:strongCell];` in the block get the correct Value.

I don't know why they are different?

Comment: Your question is unclear, provide more context.

Comment: You are not calling collectionView.reloadData() after deletion, and hence you don't get the correct indexpath after delete

Comment: Show the code that sets `clickButtonBlock`.

Comment: @kapsym Thank you .you are the right . reloadData reload all the NSIndexPath. Before the question , I always think reloadData will reload all Data and scroll to the top of the UICollectionView

Comment: @Creator Happy to help. Added the same as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `collectionView.reloadData()` after deletion, and hence you don't get the correct indexpath after delete.

Please call the method and then check.